# C++ template mechanism to get the number of function arguments, which would work for lambdas and normal functions

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda

I am trying to implement a mechanism, which would provide me some information about the template argument function type.
Main idea is to get the number of arguments, return type, total sum of sizes of each argument.
I have something running for lambdas based on [this entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943525/is-it-possible-to-figure-out-the-parameter-type-and-return-type-of-a-lambda).

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct sumSizeOfArgs {
    enum { totalSize = sizeof(typename std::decay<T>::type) + sumSizeOfArgs<Args...>::totalSize };
};

template<typename T>
struct sumSizeOfArgs<T> {
    enum  {totalSize = sizeof(typename std::decay<T>::type)};
};
}             
template <typename T>
struct function_traits : public function_traits<decltype(&T::operator())>
{};

template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... Args>

struct function_traits<ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Args...) const>
{
  enum { arity = sizeof...(Args) };

  typedef ReturnType result_type;

enum { totalSize = sumSizeOfArgs<Args...>::totalSize };

template <size_t i>
struct arg
{
    typedef typename std::tuple_element<i, std::tuple<Args...>>::type type;
};
};
```

However, indeed this code does not work for normal functions types such as

```
 function_traits<void()>
```

it does not have an operator(). I would greatly appreciate, any suggestion to make this code work for both cases.
Thanks,

Comment: Your `sumSizeOfArgs` is of limited utility, as it will choke when instantiated with 0 template-arguments. You might want to correct that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slightly improved original part:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename... Args>
struct sumSizeOfArgs
{
    static constexpr size_t totalSize = 0;
};

template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct sumSizeOfArgs<T, Args...>
{
    static constexpr size_t totalSize = sizeof(typename std::decay<T>::type)
                                        + sumSizeOfArgs<Args...>::totalSize;
};

template <typename T>
struct sumSizeOfArgs<T>
{
    static constexpr size_t totalSize = sizeof(typename std::decay<T>::type);
};

template <typename T>
struct function_traits_impl;

template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct function_traits_impl<ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Args...)>
{
    static constexpr size_t arity = sizeof...(Args);

    using result_type = ReturnType;

    static constexpr size_t totalSize = sumSizeOfArgs<Args...>::totalSize;

    template <size_t i>
    struct arg
    {
        using type = typename std::tuple_element<i, std::tuple<Args...>>::type;
    };
};

template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct function_traits_impl<ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Args...) const>
    : function_traits_impl<ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Args...)> {};
```

New part starts here (traits' class partial specialization for functions):

```
template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct function_traits_impl<ReturnType(Args...)>
{
    static constexpr size_t arity = sizeof...(Args);

    using result_type = ReturnType;

    static constexpr size_t totalSize = sumSizeOfArgs<Args...>::totalSize;

    template <size_t i>
    struct arg
    {
        using type = typename std::tuple_element<i, std::tuple<Args...>>::type;
    };
};

template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct function_traits_impl<ReturnType(*)(Args...)>
    : function_traits_impl<ReturnType(Args...)> {};
```

Crucial part is here (determining the presence of `operator()`):

```
template <typename T, typename V = void>
struct function_traits
    : function_traits_impl<T> {};

template <typename T>
struct function_traits<T, decltype((void)&T::operator())>
    : function_traits_impl<decltype(&T::operator())> {};
```

Test:

```
int main()
{
    static_assert(function_traits<void()>::arity == 0, "!");

    static_assert(function_traits<void(int)>::arity == 1, "!");

    static_assert(function_traits<void(*)(int, float)>::arity == 2, "!");  

    auto lambda = [] (int, float, char) {};
    static_assert(function_traits<decltype(lambda)>::arity == 3, "!");

    auto mutable_lambda = [] (int, float, char, double) mutable {};
    static_assert(function_traits<decltype(mutable_lambda)>::arity == 4, "!");
}
```

[**DEMO 1**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d086c0db9d7fadc9)

---

Or even simpler, with a single trait class:

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct function_traits_defs
{
    static constexpr size_t arity = sizeof...(Args);

    using result_type = ReturnType;

    template <size_t i>
    struct arg
    {
        using type = typename std::tuple_element<i, std::tuple<Args...>>::type;
    };
};

template <typename T>
struct function_traits_impl;

template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct function_traits_impl<ReturnType(Args...)>
    : function_traits_defs<ReturnType, Args...> {};

template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct function_traits_impl<ReturnType(*)(Args...)>
    : function_traits_defs<ReturnType, Args...> {};

template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct function_traits_impl<ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Args...)>
    : function_traits_defs<ReturnType, Args...> {};

template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct function_traits_impl<ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Args...) const>
    : function_traits_defs<ReturnType, Args...> {};

// + other cv-ref-variations

template <typename T, typename V = void>
struct function_traits
    : function_traits_impl<T> {};

template <typename T>
struct function_traits<T, decltype((void)&T::operator())>
    : function_traits_impl<decltype(&T::operator())> {};

int main()
{
    static_assert(function_traits<void()>::arity == 0, "!");

    static_assert(function_traits<void(int)>::arity == 1, "!");

    static_assert(function_traits<void(*)(int, float)>::arity == 2, "!");  

    auto lambda = [] (int, float, char) {};
    static_assert(function_traits<decltype(lambda)>::arity == 3, "!");

    auto mutable_lambda = [] (int, float, char, double) mutable {};
    static_assert(function_traits<decltype(mutable_lambda)>::arity == 4, "!");

    struct Functor
    {
        void operator()(int) {}
    };
    static_assert(function_traits<Functor>::arity == 1, "!");
}
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be9f17a14e156b7e)

---

**Note:** Unfortunately none of the above solutions will work for generic lambdas, related discussion is [Arity of a generic lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25704173/arity-of-a-generic-lambda)

Comment: Worth noting that taking the address of `operator()` obviously won't work for polymorphic lambdas.

Comment: @T.C. noted as suggested

Comment: This looks great thank you! Can you explain to me this part actually, what is this specialization why (void)?            template <typename T>
struct function_traits<T, decltype((void)&T::operator())>
    : function_traits_impl<decltype(&T::operator())> {};

Comment: @edorado: (1). The *name lookup* finds *primary template*; (2). Compiler searches for specialization (using `void` as second argument); (3). Compiler tries to instantiate the specialization with `decltype((void)&T::operator())`; (4). If the expression in `decltype` is *well-formed*, it gets casted to `void` and hence is treated by compiler as viable *partial-specialization* that can be used (which is designed to work with `operator()`), otherwise, it falls back to *primary template*, and uses that class template for functions. [See video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a0FliKwcwXE&t=29m06s)

Comment: Really minor thing, you could add a specialization for `ReturnType(&)(Args...)`, or put a template in front that decays T. That way it works for things like types deduced from rvalue refs such as here `template<typename T> void foo(T&& f) { function_traits<T>::arity; }`