# Detecting whether or not a callable object is binary (including generic constrained lambdas)

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, c++17, detection-idiom

I'm trying to detect whether or not a *callable object* is binary *(i.e. if its `operator()` takes two arguments)*. I want to perform this check on lambdas, including **generic lambdas** and **constrained generic lambdas** *(e.g. with trailing `std::enable_if_t` return type)*.

---

**NOTE:** this is **not** a duplicate of ["arity of a generic lambda"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25704173/arity-of-a-generic-lambda). I only care about checking whether or not a generic lambda is binary, and I can already do that for *unconstrained generic lambdas* or *generic lambdas that do not use the arguments in their body*.

---

My current approach consists in applying one of the techniques described in [Kris Jusiak's Boost.DI C++Now 2015 talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=comZthFv3PM): `any_type`. It basically is a class which can be implicitly converted to any other class.

```
struct any_type
{
    template <typename T>
    constexpr operator T() const noexcept
    {
        return {};
    }
};
```

After defining `any_type`, I'm using the [detection idiom](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) to check if a particular callable object can be invoked with two arguments:

```
template<class T>
using is_binary_callable_impl = decltype(std::declval<T>()(any_type{}, any_type{}));

template <typename T>
using is_binary_callable = std::experimental::is_detected<is_binary_callable_impl, T>;
```

This approach works well for both non-generic and generic lambdas...

```
auto unary_nongeneric = [](int){};
auto unary_generic = [](auto){};
auto binary_nongeneric = [](int, float){};
auto binary_generic = [](auto, auto){};

static_assert(!is_binary_callable<decltype(unary_nongeneric)>{});
static_assert(!is_binary_callable<decltype(unary_generic)>{});
static_assert(is_binary_callable<decltype(binary_nongeneric)>{});
static_assert(is_binary_callable<decltype(binary_generic)>{});
```

...but horribly fails when the argument is accessed with an interface that is not supported by `any_type` or when the lambda is constrained:

```
auto binary_generic_constrained = [](auto, auto x) 
    -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<std::decay_t<decltype(x)>>{}> {};

// Fails!
static_assert(is_binary_callable<decltype(binary_generic_constrained)>{});
```

> error: static assertion failed

```
auto binary_generic_body = [](auto, auto x){ x.something(); };

// Compilation error!
static_assert(is_binary_callable<decltype(binary_generic_constrained)>{});
```

> error: 'struct any_type' has no member named 'something'

[**The full code is on available here (on wandbox)**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/lIRrfqRYEWFBf0bj).

---

Assuming I'm on the right track with `any_type`, is there any way to ignore the lambda's return type and the lambda's body? In more detail:

- Is it possible to check whether or not a generic constrained lambda is binary?
- Is it possible to check whether or not a generic lambda that tries to access a specific member of its arguments is binary?

Otherwise, is there any other approach that could work here?

Comment: @wasthishelpful: added a comment mentioning why I believe this question is not a duplicate. I can, in fact, already check the arity of non-variadic generic lambdas - I have problems with constrained generic lambdas and lambdas that try to access the generic argument in their body.

Comment: I saw your edit, but I still think that is a duplicate. The approach in the question is limited because it doesn't handle generic lambdas. But [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25704767/6612932) relies on a `fake_anything` similar to your `any_type` (while your type is far simpler), and achieves the same result: the type erasure inherent to your approach makes it unsuitable with constrained lambdas

Comment: @wasthishelpful I agree. The answers focus on restricted templates, too.