# Specializing function template based on lambda arity

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++17, arity

I am trying to specialize a templated function based on the arity of the lambda that I pass to it as an argument. This is what I have come up with for a solution:

```
template<typename Function, bool>
struct helper;

template<typename Function>
struct helper<Function, false>
{
    auto operator()(Function&& func)
    {
        std::cout << "Called 2 argument version.\n";
        return func(1, 2);
    }
};

template<typename Function>
struct helper<Function, true>
{
    auto operator()(Function&& func)
    {
        std::cout << "Called 3 argument version.\n";
        return func(1, 2, 3);
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct B
{
    T a;
    const T someVal() const { return a; }
};

template<typename Function, typename T>
auto higherOrderFun(Function&& func, const T& a)
{
    return helper<Function, std::is_invocable<Function, decltype(a.someVal()), decltype(a.someVal()), decltype(a.someVal())>::value>{}(std::forward<Function>(func));
}


int main()
{
    B<int> b;
    std::cout << higherOrderFun([](auto x, auto y) {return x+y; }, b) << "\n";
    std::cout << higherOrderFun([](auto x, auto y, auto z) {return x + y+z; }, b) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this in a more elegant manner? I've looked through this: [Arity of a generic lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25704173/arity-of-a-generic-lambda)

However, the latest solution (florestan's) turns all arguments into `aribtrary_t`, so one has to cast them back inside of each lambda, which I do not find ideal. Ideally I would have liked to directly specialize the templated `higherOrderFun` with SFINAE, but as it is I use a helper class in order to achieve that. Is there a more straighforward way? For instance to apply SFINAE directly to `higherOrderFun` without relying on a `helper` class? The whole point of this is to not have to change `higherOrderFun` into `higherOrderFun2` and `higherOrderFun3`, but rather have the compiler deduce the correct specialization from the lambda and the given argument (`const T& a`).

I should mention that I also don't care about the type of the arguments to the function - just about their count, so I would have changed `decltype(a.someVal())` to `auto` in my example if that was possible (maybe there's a way to circumvent explicitly defining the types?).

Comment: What if `func` can both accept two arguments and three arguments?

Comment: *"aribtrary_t, so one has to cast them back inside of each lambda"*. No it is only used in un-evaluated context (so don't instantiate the generic lambdas if any).

Comment: @Jarod42 I tried using his `arity_v` for SFINAE in msvc2017 and it required the cast inside each lambda since it apparently instantiated it with `arbitrary_t` when I used `arity_v`. I could try to create a minimal example when I get back though.

Comment: How, indeed its traits isn't working as we might expect [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ajJzAf).

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, this is precisely what I meant. Thank you for making an example, I already mentioned this in the original thread.

Comment: @L.F. In the specific case I have in mind, I do not expect such functions, so this is a non-issue in this case. Ideally however, one should be able to query if those exist. This means that a desirable behaviour would for example return the maximum arity, and there would be additional arity traits that would be used to test for the existence of an overload with a specific arity (for example `arity_v<F,2>`). But as I said - this is not specifically regarding my problem, it's just something I believe would be useful in general. My problem would have been easily solved if there was `airty<F,N>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use different overloads:

```
template<typename Function>
auto higherOrderFun(Function&& func)
-> decltype(std::forward<Function>(func)(1, 2, 3))
{
    return std::forward<Function>(func)(1, 2, 3);
}

template<typename Function>
auto higherOrderFun(Function&& func)
-> decltype(std::forward<Function>(func)(1, 2))
{
    return std::forward<Function>(func)(1, 2);
}
```

Possibly with overload priority as

```
 struct low_priority {};
 struct high_priority : low_priority{};

template<typename Function>
auto higherOrderFunImpl(Function&& func, low_priority)
-> decltype(std::forward<Function>(func)(1, 2))
{
    return std::forward<Function>(func)(1, 2);
}

template<typename Function>
auto higherOrderFunImpl(Function&& func, high_priority)
-> decltype(std::forward<Function>(func)(1, 2))
{
    return std::forward<Function>(func)(1, 2);
}

template<typename Function>
auto higherOrderFun(Function&& func)
-> decltype(higherOrderFun(std::forward<Function>(func), high_priority{}))
{
    return higherOrderFun(std::forward<Function>(func), high_priority{});
}
```

If you want to use the [arity traits from florestan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49439207/2684539), it might result in:

```
template<typename F>
decltype(auto) higherOrderFun(F&& func)
{
    if constexpr (arity_v<std::decay_t<F>, MaxArity> == 3)
    {
        return std::forward<F>(func)(1, 2, 3);
    }
    else if constexpr (arity_v<std::decay_t<F>, MaxArity> == 2)
    {
        return std::forward<F>(func)(1, 2);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this if I decide to not directly return the result of the function? Note also that the 1,2,3 were simply placeholders - in general the arguments would be taken possibly from `a.someVal()` or something similar. (I should have clarified this in hindsight). I like the priority idea.

Comment: Yes, you might replace `1, 2, 3` by `a.someval()`.

Answer (score 3):

The following template gives me the number of parameters to a lambda, a `std::function`, or a plain function pointer. This seems to cover all the basics. So, you specialize on `n_lambda_parameters<T>::n`, and plug this into your template. Depending on your specific use cases, you may need to employ the facilities offered by `std::remove_reference_t` or `std::decay_t`, to wrap this.

Tested with g++ 9. Requires `std::void_t` from C++17, plenty of examples of simulating `std::void_t` pre C++17 can be found elsewhere...

```
#include <functional>

// Plain function pointer.

template<typename T> struct n_func_parameters;

template<typename T, typename ...Args>
struct n_func_parameters<T(Args...)> {

    static constexpr size_t n=sizeof...(Args);
};

// Helper wrapper to tease out lambda operator()'s type.

// Tease out closure's operator()...

template<typename T, typename> struct n_extract_callable_parameters;

// ... Non-mutable closure
template<typename T, typename ret, typename ...Args>
struct n_extract_callable_parameters<T, ret (T::*)(Args...) const> {

    static constexpr size_t n=sizeof...(Args);
};

// ... Mutable closure
template<typename T, typename ret, typename ...Args>
struct n_extract_callable_parameters<T, ret (T::*)(Args...)> {

    static constexpr size_t n=sizeof...(Args);
};

// Handle closures, SFINAE fallback to plain function pointers.

template<typename T, typename=void> struct n_lambda_parameters
    : n_func_parameters<T> {};

template<typename T>
struct n_lambda_parameters<T, std::void_t<decltype(&T::operator())>>
    : n_extract_callable_parameters<T, decltype(&T::operator())> {};


#include <iostream>

void foo(int, char, double=0)
{
}

int main()
{
    auto closure=
        [](int x, int y)
    // With or without mutable, here.
        {
        };

    std::cout << n_lambda_parameters<decltype(closure)>::n
          << std::endl; // Prints 2.

    std::cout << n_lambda_parameters<decltype(foo)>::n
          << std::endl; // Prints 3.

    std::cout << n_lambda_parameters<std::function<void (int)>>::n
          << std::endl; // Prints 1.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Notice that OP uses generic lambda, so your solution won't work (as for any overloaded `operator()` BTW).

Comment: Unfortunately a direct copy-paste of your code into msvc, or godbolt's latest msvc ver (19.21) fails to compile. The first part of the error reads: `'n_extract_callable_parameters<T,_Ret (__thiscall std::_Func_class<_Ret,int>::* )(int) const>': base class undefined`
I am unsure whether you're doing something that goes against the standard, or if it's msvc that doesn't support the standard adequately. But eitherway it fails on a major compiler.