# Can I change the template argument deduction order for a generic variadic lambda?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, c++20, generic-lambda

Take the following code, which is a simplified example:

```cpp
template <typename F>
void foo(F f) {
    //bool some = is_variadic_v<F>; // Scenario #1
    bool some = true;               // Scenario #2
    f(int(some), int(some));
}

int main() {
    auto some = [](int i, int j) {
        std::cout << i << " " << j << '\n';
    };
    
    foo([&some](auto... params) {
        some(params...);
    });
}
```

A function takes a generic variadic lambda and calls it with a fixed set of arguments. This lambda itself then just calls another function/lambda with a matching prototype.
As one could expect, in scenario 2, when `f` is called inside `foo`, the compiler will deduce `params...` to be the parameter pack `{1, 1}`.

For scenario #1, I am using a code from another [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49439207) to deduce the *arity* of a callable object. If however such an object is callable with more than a pre-defined maximum amount of arguments, it is considered "variadic". In detail, `is_variadic_v` will employ a form of expression SFINAE where it is attempted to call the function object with a decreasing number of arguments having an "arbitrary type" that is implictly convertible to anything.

The problem is now that apparently, the compiler will deduce F (and along its argument pack) during this metacode, and if it is variadic (such as in this case), it deduces F as a lambda taking the dummy arguments, i.e. something like `main()::lambda(<arbitrary_type<0>, arbitrary_type<1>, arbitrary_type<2>, ..., arbitrary_type<N>>)` if N is the "variadic limit" from above. Now `params...` is deduced as `arbitrary_type<1>, arbitrary_type<2>, ...` and correspondingly, the call `some(params...)` will fail.
This behaviour can be demonstrated in [this little code example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ojl8VPeaCoTsALCC):

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

constexpr int max_arity = 12; // if a function takes more arguments than that, it will be considered variadic

struct variadic_type { };

// it is templated, to be able to create a
// "sequence" of arbitrary_t's of given size and
// hence, to 'simulate' an arbitrary function signature.
template <auto>
struct arbitrary_type {
    // this type casts implicitly to anything,
    // thus, it can represent an arbitrary type.
    template <typename T>
    operator T&&();

    template <typename T>
    operator T&();
};

template <
    typename F, auto ...Ints,
    typename = decltype(std::declval<F>()(arbitrary_type<Ints>{ }...))
>
constexpr auto test_signature(std::index_sequence<Ints...> s) {
    return std::integral_constant<int, size(s)>{ };
}

template <auto I, typename F>
constexpr auto arity_impl(int) -> decltype(test_signature<F>(std::make_index_sequence<I>{ })) {
    return { };
}

template <auto I, typename F, typename = std::enable_if_t<(I > 0)>>
constexpr auto arity_impl(...) {
    // try the int overload which will only work,
    // if F takes I-1 arguments. Otherwise this
    // overload will be selected and we'll try it 
    // with one element less.
    return arity_impl<I - 1, F>(0);
}

template <typename F, auto MaxArity>
constexpr auto arity_impl() {
    // start checking function signatures with max_arity + 1 elements
    constexpr auto tmp = arity_impl<MaxArity+1, F>(0);
    if constexpr (tmp == MaxArity+1) 
        return variadic_type{ }; // if that works, F is considered variadic
    else return tmp; // if not, tmp will be the correct arity of F
}

template <typename F, auto MaxArity = max_arity>
constexpr auto arity(F&&) { return arity_impl<std::decay_t<F>, MaxArity>(); }

template <typename F, auto MaxArity = max_arity>
constexpr auto arity_v = arity_impl<std::decay_t<F>, MaxArity>();

template <typename F, auto MaxArity = max_arity>
constexpr bool is_variadic_v = std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<decltype(arity_v<F, MaxArity>)>, variadic_type>;

template <typename F>
void foo(F f) {
    bool some = is_variadic_v<F>;
    //bool some = true;
    f(int(some), int(some));
}

int main() {
    auto some = [](int i, int j) {
        std::cout << i << " " << j << '\n';
    };
    
    foo([&some](auto... params) {
        some(params...);
    });
}
```

Can I prevent this behaviour? Can I force the compiler to re-deduce the parameter list?

---

**EDIT:**

An additional peculiarity is that the compiler seems to act kind of schizophrenic. When I change the contents of `foo` to

```
foo([&some](auto... params) {
    // int foo = std::index_sequence<sizeof...(params)>{ };
    std::cout << sizeof...(params) << '\n';
});
```

the compiler will create a program that will print `2` in this example. If however I include the commented line (which, as it makes no sense, should trigger a compiler diagnostic), I get confronted with

```
error: cannot convert 'std::index_sequence<13>' {aka 'std::integer_sequence<long unsigned int, 13>'} to 'int' in initialization
   85 |         int foo = std::index_sequence<sizeof...(params)>{ };
```

so does the compiler now deduces `sizeof...(params)` to be `2` and `13` at the same time? Or did he change his mind and chooses now `13` just because I added another statement into the lambda? Compilation will also fail if I instead choose a `static_assert(2 == sizeof...(params));`. So the compiler deduces `sizeof...(params) == 2`, except if I ask him whether he did deduce `2`, because then he didn't.

Apparently, it is very decisive for the parameter pack deduction what is written inside the lambda. Is it just me or does this behaviour really look pathologic?

Comment: *"does the compiler now deduce sizeof...(params) to be 2 and 13 at the same time"* Both! But not at the same time. It *validates* ("instantiates" is the right word) the lambda body for both cases (that is, for each set of parameter types you try to call the lambda with).

Comment: I get XY-problem vibes. Why do you need to know if the lambda is variadic or not?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat This sounds fantastic and frightening to me at the same time. In usual SFINAE, it will only remove overload candidates if instantiation yields an erro in the return type or (template) arguments, but not the body.

According to your theory, if I add static_assert(2 == sizeof...(params)); before the cout, it should still compile, right? But it does not! There's something I don't get.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat About the XY: I have a function that will instantiate a compile-time loop N times, N being the arity of a passed function. If that function however is variadic, I assume a maximal sensible loop count, which is generally not equal to the limit where I consider the function as "variadic".

Comment: it is rather confusing that you are talking of two different versions of the code and what seems the important part is not included in the question. Links can rot, also links to other SO questions/answers. What if that answer gets edited? Please include all the code in your question

Comment: @Jodocus *"According to your theory, if I add static_assert"* Lambda body is not considered to be a part of the so-called *immedate context*, so any error in it will be a hard error (that is, will abort the compilation, rather than be detected with SFINAE). It seems in this case the lambda body is only instantiated (and because of that, validated) to determine the return type. If you add `-> void` to the lambda, your wandbox example will compile.

Comment: *"I have a function that will instantiate a compile-time loop N times"* Can you give more details? What the loops are for? Are you trying to call the lambda with every possible combination of arguments?

Comment: @idclev463035818 Sorry, I added the complete code to the question.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Say I have a callback function, taking N (integer) arguments. Each argument runs in a certain range [start, end] that depends on the previous arguments. The metaprogram generates a nested loop for each argument and keeps nesting loops until number of loops  == Arity of callback, s.t. the callback gets called for each combination in a well-defined order. In the variadic case, there is a maximum number of nested loops I want to generate. I need this pattern a lot, so I want to generate this code automatically by a metaprogram. I hope this adds a little clarity.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat *It seems in this case the lambda body is only instantiated (and because of that, validated) to determine the return type.* Yes, this works! Though the details of the rules stay foggy to me, I still haven't got a take-home message there. Is it like the compiler has a deduction candidate and when he enters the body of the lambda to deduce the return type, he discards it and also deduces new argument types (in this case, the list of arbitrary_type<>)?